# #if DEBUG not working on a Windows Service release build

Tags: c#

In the constructor of my Windows Service I have some code within a #if DEBUG condition:

```
#if DEBUG
            var container = CompositionRoot.DiBootstrapper.Initialize();
            _initializeApplication = container.Resolve<IInitializeApplication>();
            _initializeApplication.Initialize();
#endif
```

When I compile/build the the project in release mode and install it as a Windows Service, the code within the #if DEBUG condition is executed.

I would only like the code to run when I debug the application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's very unlikely that that's what's happening. Please verify that the *installed* assembly is built without the DEBUG compiler flag (in *theory*, your Release build configuration could set the DEBUG compiler flag), and that there's no other place the same code runs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ensure that the "DEBUG" constant is not defined in Release mode.

[image]

Also, verify that your project is set to build in Release mode when the solution is in Release mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // ....
}
```

instead of the compile time constant to achive this. The code will allways be compiled into your code but only executed if you are debugging your application. Please be aware that this will also be executed if someone else attaches a debugger to your app.

However: Most likely you have configured something wrong.

Inside Visual Studio, go to "BUILD -> Configuration Manager" and verify that the specific project is set to "DEBUG".

If that is the case and your project has more than one assembly: verify that your release build of your main exe uses your newly generated Release Build for assembly references and not an old reference which is referenced from inside the `bin/debug` folder.

It looks you use IOC so maybe your main assembly `A` has no direct reference to the assembly which contains the `#DEBUG` constant `B`. So after a change to `B` if you build `A` the project `B` is not rebuild. You can solve this by right clicking your solution and select `Build dependencies`, in the drop down box select `A` and check `B`

Comment: not related at all with OP question. This is true if a debugger isAttached to current process. OP has problem with a code that should not be compiled in release mode.

Comment: @GianPaolo Op said `I would only like the code to run when I debug the application. Any suggestions?` So this is a alternate suggestion. I also included possible cases which could cause his code to be executed in production. If will make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Either your service is still build in debug mode (check the configuration manager) or you have specified a conditional compilation symbol in your release mode (check the project properties)

Answer (score -1):

Check the project configuration, then select the **Release**. Try to uncheck the **Define DEBUG constant**.